# Notice : pg_update(): Invalid field name (accion) in values in C:\xampp\htdocs\webcontratos\administrador\seccion\dependencias.php on line 26

Tags: php, postgresql

Soy nuevo en el ámbito de la programación con php y postgres, revisando la documentación de php para el motor de postgres, y a pesar de eso, me encuentro con algunos problemas, que por mi inexperiencia no he podido resolver.
Lo que hoy me trae aquí es en la utilización de una funcion **[pg_update()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pg-update.php);**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, el problema surge cuando se ejecuta el boton **Seleccionar** para posteriormente **Modificar** que se encuentran en un form:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado esperado era que modificara la inserción hecha, sin embargo el problema no es la sintaxis sino que me está tomando a **$accion** como un valor dentro de la tabla:

> Notice: pg_update(): Invalid field name (accion) in values in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\webcontratos\administrador\seccion\dependencias.php
> on line
> 26

Cabe recalcar que todo lo mencionado anteriormente se encuentra en un solo archivo .php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba de eliminar esa clave `accion` del `$_POST` mediante [unset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php) en la linea anterior donde pretendas usar `$_POST` para rellenar los campos de la tabla, de este modo:

```
unset($_POST['accion']);
```

Ya nos diras si te sirve.

Comment: Funcionó... lo malo, tapa un hoyo y se abren otros 10 

pg_update(): Expects NULL or string for PostgreSQL date field (fecha_nom) in

Se esperaba un nulo?

Comment: Revisa el input con el `name="fecha_nom"` a ver si esta bien puesto en tu formulario y se envia correctamente dentro del mismo.  Otra cosa, en tu pregunta no debes usar imágenes para mostrar código, porque nos dificultas la tarea de leerlo y de repasarlo debidamente para poder ayudarte. Puedes editar tu pregunta mediante en enlace al pie de la misma que pone **Editar** para corregir eso y pegar el código como texto.  Y no, no es que espere un NULL, sino que acepta valores tipo NULL o String en ese campo de tu tabla porque así lo tienes definido en ella, pero no recibe ni uno ni lo otro.